# how to change variable name when converting jar to DLL?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

Basically when i am converting an AAR to DLL there is same method name and variable name present in java code.

Means java class is implementing interface runnable, so default method of runnable is run. And also the class contain same name as run of boolean .

I think changing variable name is much more convenient than changing a method name which is implemented by interface.below is java code inside my jar:

```
public class Tailer
  implements Runnable
{
.....
private volatile boolean run = true; 
......
......

protected boolean getRun()
  {
    .....
    ....
    return this.run;
  }

public void run()
  {
    ....
    ....
  }

}
```

I have used following code and it is not working.

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.apache.commons.io.input']/class[@name='Tailer']/field[@name='run']" 
      name="propertyName">runvariable</attr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: "is not working" isnt a working problem description. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Then: the propertyName says "runvariable", but the source calls it "run"?!